# Confusion between BES and BIS for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am trying to develop a simple BB OS < 7.X application that the only thing it does is having push notifications enabled.
I have dealt before with push notifications (android , wp7 , iOS) but the BB implementation is really something..

I know that in order for a device to be able to get push notifications , BIS or BES must be enabled. All good till now , with a simple call you can enable that.

However what is the difference exactly? I am supposed to develop an application for users that most of them use BIS of course. However the phone , i ve been given to develop on has BES enabled.

Does this affect at all my "code" on developing? I would think of course not , but i ve seen examples of code , implementing push , that for example with BES you dont need to provide a push port in your code etc etc.

I am quoting :

```
In the case of BIS, your carrier operates the server. Everything from BIS to your handheld
is encrypted, but that’s about the extent of the security features. The
carrier can decide what applications run on your phone,and how applications
communicate with the Internet.

For BES, your company operates the server, and usually has it sitting somewhere
within the corporate network. The IT department controls all  aspect of the BES
server, and it’s likely sitting in a nice and secure location.
```

What "server"  are they talking about ? I know "my server" , cause i ve written it and it contacts the BIS to send push notifications , it registers my users tokens and so on. So what is this "new server" that my company has? My company has no server of any kind as far as i know. We just have a phone with BES enabled...

I dont understand how is the server side connected to the client side here. Is it different to develop push through BES and different through BIS ? If the server is BES but the client has BIS ? If someone could clear a bit out these things to me i would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these links:
http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/push_service_overview.html
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/03/introducing-blackberry-push-services-to-developers/

In short, BIS is a proxy service managed by RIM, and BES is like a corporate BIS server managed by a company.

As for the push, you can select whether you need BIS only or BIS+BES in the [registration form for evaluation](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121) (There's a "Transport for Pushes" combo). When you are going to [register for production](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8207), instead you choice between push service type (plus or essential).